# Return Literal vs Pointer

Tags: pointers, go, literals

Trying to make a slice and having problems with literals and pointers.  It looks like when appending onto my slice it does not like the fact of being handed a pointer.  For instance I have a package type I made called components and holds type Component.  See below.

```
package components

import ()

type Component struct {
Name    string
Element string
Color   string
}

func (c *Component) SetName(name string) {
    c.Name = name
}

func (c *Component) SetElement(element string) {
c.Element = element
}

func (c *Component) SetColor(color string) {
    c.Color = color
}

func (c *Component) GetName() string {
    return c.Name
}

func (c *Component) GetColor() string {
    return c.Color
}

func (c *Component) GetElement() string {
    return c.Element
}

func NewComponent(name string, color string, element string) *Component {
    c := &Component{}
    c.SetName(name)
    c.SetColor(color)
    c.SetElement(element)
    return c
}
```

Now I am attempting to make a slice to put all my components into I am making spellcasting components like Snow,Sand,Sunbeam,Springwater etc.

```
    //Creating SpringWater Component with Setters
    SpringWater := components.Component{}
    SpringWater.SetName("SpringWater")
    SpringWater.SetColor("Blue")
    SpringWater.SetElement("Water")

    //Creating Sand Component using the Constructor
    Sand := components.NewComponent("Sand", "Red", "Earth")
```

**ERROR HAPPENS HERE ON COMPLILE:**
    compSlice := make([]components.Component, 5)
    compSlice = append(compSlice, SpringWater, Sand)

**ERROR: Cannot use Sand as type (*components.Component) as type components.Component in append.**

Now using the Setters and Setting the Fields DIRECT I can add it to a slice however using the method it returns a *pointer and the Slice will not comply.  I am just not understanding and having a difficult issue.  Keep in mind I am new to programming and basically come from scripting so forgive me on this and have seen similar questions but do not understand in this context.

Comment: And a comment on your design. If you want to hide your struct members behind functions like `SetName` then you should make them lower-case. If you make them UpperCase then they are public to everyone for use directly. And I'd do it that way because I consider function-hiding to be silly, although you need it for Go interfaces, but whatever.

Comment: OK I will mess around with it some more and let you guys know what I come up with or if I am still struggling.  I had no idea helpful folks would reply to me so soon wow!  Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Go hides the difference between values and pointers in several places, but not everywhere.

In this situation you will have to dereference `Sand` and write `compSlice = append(compSlice, SpringWater, *Sand)`

Answer (score 1):

`component.Component` and `*component.Component` are different types in Go.  You're gonna want that slice to be `compSlice := make([]*component.Component, 5)` or `append(compSlice, *SpringWater)`.

The methods you defined all deal with `*component.Component` not `component.Component`.

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers are correct.

In my answer, i've added your code to the `main` package and i've added some comments in the `main function` to help you understanding what is going in your code.

Here is the code with comments:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Component struct {
    Name    string
    Element string
    Color   string
}

func (c *Component) SetName(name string) {
    c.Name = name
}

func (c *Component) SetElement(element string) {
    c.Element = element
}

func (c *Component) SetColor(color string) {
    c.Color = color
}

func (c *Component) GetName() string {
    return c.Name
}

func (c *Component) GetColor() string {
    return c.Color
}

func (c *Component) GetElement() string {
    return c.Element
}

func NewComponent(name string, color string, element string) *Component {
    c := &Component{}
    c.SetName(name)
    c.SetColor(color)
    c.SetElement(element)
    return c
}

func main() {

    // NewComponent will return a *Component type
    // So Sand will we a *Component type
    Sand := NewComponent("Sand", "Red", "Earth")
    // You can create a slice of []*Component
    compSlice := make([]*Component, 5)
    // Then append Sand which is a *Component Slice
    compSlice = append(compSlice, Sand)
    // Result: Will be the reference of Sand which is a reference of Component struct
    // [<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc8200121b0]
    fmt.Println(compSlice)
    // Or, you can create a lice of []Component
    newCompSlice := make([]Component, 5)
    // Then append the reference of Sand which is *Sand
    newCompSlice = append(newCompSlice, *Sand)
    // Result: will be the literal Component struct
    // [{  } {  } {  } {  } {  } {Sand Earth Red}]
    fmt.Println(newCompSlice)
}
```

Also, you can run it in: [repl.it](https://repl.it/EvLP/0)